# Laravel - Every new day I have this error : failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, permissions, permission-denied

i tried by giving permission (775) to bootstrap/cache and storage folder - it works fine on that day but next day it gives error again with new created log file.

> The stream or file "/var/www/public_html/myProject/storage/logs/laravel-2021-03-31.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/public_html/myProject/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:111

Comment: Depending on how the `laravel-{day}-log` file is created, it can have incompatible permissions. If the log is created via a Console command (like in a scheduler CRON or similar), or via logging/an exception on the Website, it can have different permissions (root vs webuser, etc etc). I think this was solve via ACLs on the `storage/logs` folder, but I haven't seen this issue in a while

Comment: the **laravel-{day}-log** file is created via CRON.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution here:

i have two users on linux server
1 : ubuntu
2 : www-data

i added ubuntu user to www-data group and same as wwww-data to ubuntu group.
so now both users can read there files,

second thing i did is -> i updated app/config/logging.php

and define the permissions (0666) for newly created log file for "daily" and "single".

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/{laravel_project_name}
```

link:

https://dev.to/613596/permission-denied-for-laravel-8-storage-logs-solved-2021-12ld

Answer (score -2):

You have permission issue in your path `/var/www/public_html/myProject/storage/logs/`.

Try to run the following command

1. Change the files/directories group to apache/nginx, I used `www-data` it's the default user of apache on Ubuntu (Use your http server user/group name instead of `www-data`)

   `sudo chown :www-data -R /var/www/public_html/myProject/storage/`
2. Now change the file permission once again

   `sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/public_html/myProject/storage/`
3. You can also add `UID, GID, SID` to handle more efficiently